# java persistence error. javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence")

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, persistence

the version of tomcat ee is 7.0.81
I try to use java persistence to store data in database. but when I add the both dependencys and create the persistence.xml file. I will occur some error.
here is the dependency, I use 2.2 version of persistence. and 5.3.7 hibernate

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

here is the config file.  I just follow the internet, then change the url, user, and password to correct.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="persistence">
        <description>Hibernate JPA Demo</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.Driver"
                      value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/property?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=GMT&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"
                      value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                      value="sa@123" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql"
                      value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"
                      value="validate"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

here is the error, when I try to start my project.

```
SEVERE: Unable to load Persistence Unit from EAR: C:\project\propertyByEJB\target\propertyByEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT, module: file:/C:/project/propertyByEJB/target/propertyByEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/. Exception: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence"). Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence>
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence"). Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:662)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1063)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:480)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:150)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.jpa.unit.JaxbPersistenceFactory.getPersistence(JaxbPersistenceFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReadDescriptors.deploy(ReadDescriptors.java:180)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:971)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1227)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5519)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1009)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWar(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:663)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:622)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:43)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:227)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:194)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:370)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:361)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:257)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```